# Insert records from multipe loops

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have the following query, which works fine. How can this query be modified to INSERT records into the table below.

```
with loop1(tour_id) as (select level from
 dual connect by level <= 10)
    ,loop2(b) as (select level from dual connect by level <= 7)
SELECT tour_id,
    'Tour ' || tour_id AS tour_name,

      
replace(listagg(CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,2))
                       
WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
                       
WHEN 2 THEN 'N'
                      
END,',')               
within group (order by b)
             ,',') AS active_days
  FROM  loop1
      cross join loop2
 group by tour_id

create table tour_hdr(
  tour_id NUMBER(4),
   tour_name VARCHAR2(20),
  active_days VARCHAR2(7)
)
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

> How can this query be modified to `INSERT` records into the table below?

Like this:

```
insert into tour_hdr (tour_id, tour_name, active_days)
with 
  loop1 (tour_id) as (select ...),
  loop2 (b)       as (select ...)
select tour_id,
       'Tour ' ||tour_id as tour_name,
       replace(listagg(...)) as active_days
from loop1 cross join loop2
group by tour_id;
```